# How can I remove values in one DataFrame where the matching value in another DataFrame is not null?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two DataFrames:

```
df1:
ticker           A        B        C
date
2022-01-01       NaN      NaN      100
2022-01-02       NaN      200      NaN
2022-01-03       100      NaN      NaN
2022-01-04       NaN      NaN      120

df2:
ticker           A        B        C
date
2022-01-02       145      233      100
2022-01-03       231      200      241
2022-01-04       100      200      422
2022-01-05       424      324      222
2022-01-06       400      421      320
```

I want to fill the values in `df2` as `np.nan` for each index and column, where the value in `df1` is not null to get the following:

```
df3:
ticker           A        B        C
date
2022-01-02       145      NaN      100
2022-01-03       NaN      200      241
2022-01-04       100      200      NaN
2022-01-05       424      324      222
2022-01-06       400      421      320
```

I am applying the following code:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    idx = df1[df1[col].notna()].index
    if df2[col][idx] == df1[col][idx]:
        df2[col][idx] = np.nan
```

However, this gives the error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How can I re-write the above loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) to align `df1` with `df2`, then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the values of `df2` for which the matching `df1` are [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
out = df2.mask(df1.reindex_like(df2).notna())
```

To modify `df2` in place:

```
df2[df1.reindex_like(df2).notna()] = float('nan')
```

Output:

```
                A      B      C
date                           
2022-01-02  145.0    NaN  100.0
2022-01-03    NaN  200.0  241.0
2022-01-04  100.0  200.0    NaN
2022-01-05  424.0  324.0  222.0
2022-01-06  400.0  421.0  320.0
```

###### combining several conditions

```
df1b = df1.reindex_like(df2)

out = df2.mask(df1b.notna()&df2.ne(df1b), df2-df1b)
```

Output:

```
              A    B    C
date                     
2022-01-02  145   33  100
2022-01-03  131  200  241
2022-01-04  100  200  302
2022-01-05  424  324  222
2022-01-06  400  421  320
```

Comment: Alright that works. But do you know what seems to be wrong with loop in the question? I can't figure out that error. I want to have a loop so I can add other conditions too.

Comment: What other conditions? You should always avoid to loop in pandas.

Comment: The other condition is if `df2[col][idx] != df1[col][idx]` then `df2[col][idx] = df2[col][idx] - df1[col][idx]`

Comment: So, instead of the NaN you want the df2-df1 value?

Comment: Yes, as a second condition. That's why I wrote the if statement.

Comment: Check my update, I combined both conditions (with AND)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. Do you have any tutorials where I can learn how to be more efficient with pandas?

Comment: No, I mostly learned using the docs and by coding ;)